# Getting error while using defer in countdown timer

Tags: angular, typescript

I am making a timer which goes 5:00, 4:59...0:00.

Getting many errors while using defer,

1. Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'void' at pipe(switchMap...
2. Expected 1 arguments, but got 2. at takeWhile
3. , expected in few places in ngOnInit
4. A 'this' parameter must be the first parameter at !this.duration
5. No overload matches this call.
   The last overload gave the following error.
   Argument of type '{ throw: Error; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<unknown, unknown>'.
   Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'throw' does not exist in type 'OperatorFunction<unknown, unknown>'.

```
time$ = timer(0, 1000).pipe(
  defer(of(this.duration)).pipe(switchMap(duration => timer(0, 1000).pipe(map(n => duration - n)),
  takeWhile(n => n >0),
  ),
  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (!this.duration) {
      throw new Error('duration is required')
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Defer doesn’t take an observable as an arg, it takes a callback function that returns an observable

Comment: I am new to angular. Can you explain a bit more? Explnation with code would be useful.